# Best technique for throwing up a table view selection dialog?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

What would be the best approach to throw up a list of vales to select from in the case:

- you are on the flipside of a simple main view/flipside iPhone app
- you have different configuration values in the flip view you want the user to be able to pick from
- you want to use a table view for the selection options
- like to be able to reuse the approach/code for each of the settings In The flip view

So I'm thinking of what the best approach would be in terms of aspects such as :

- programmatic?  No XIB perhaps
- modal or non-modal? (use of navigation controller or not to pop, or do modal)
- method to pass back the value to the parent flipview controller in manner that it knows which of the parameters to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

programmatic? No XIB perhaps

*Programmatically. But u can use tableview object added to nib file.*

modal or non-modal? (use of navigation controller or not to pop, or do modal)

*Modal. Presenting the modal view is also easier.*

method to pass back the value to the parent flipview controller in manner that it knows which of the parameters to change

*For this, you have to use the delegate pattern. To know about how to use delegate , see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294328/how-to-use-delegate-pattern-on-iphone)*