# Need Help With DidSelectRowAtIndex For UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a Root UITableView (view 1) and I have a button in the navbar that pushes to another UITableView (view 2) on the nav stack.

When I select a cell from view 2, I set it up so that it pops back to the initial view.  I want to be able to set the table's title on view 1 depending on what cell I selected from view 2.  Can anyone help me do this?

I'm not simply pushing from view 2 to view 1 which would make setting the title easier.  Perhaps I need to create some type of delegate method?

Comment: are u using popviewcontroller to pop back to view 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of delegates for this. Create a `delegate` in which u have a method that takes a `NSString` as argument and set the `delegate` as your view controller with the initial table view. Then u can get the string to display.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was leaning towards.  Can you provide some more details as I'm still learning how to work with delegates. Thanks!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294328/how-to-use-delegate-pattern-on-iphone

Comment: Thanks, is there an easier way though? Perhaps something like this before the controller is popped? `[[self parentViewController] setSomething:newSomething];`

Comment: NO I am not sure something like that is going to work.. Delegates would do the job. and once you learn to create custom delegates, those will be easy...

Comment: I looked at the link you posted and added `secondViewController.delegate = self;` when pushing to view 2, but then what do I do?

Comment: in your case u have to have it in your first view controller and then write the method definition in this class. So now have the method definition in this class and set the string here

Comment: @Jon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2148/discussion-between-7kv7-and-jon)

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is...,

1. Declare a NSString variable in your application delegate file(.h) and synthesize it in .m file.
2. Create an instance of Application Delegate in both subviews (view 1 & view 2).
3. While navigate back to previous view from View 2, set the title of application delegate's synthesized variable. (Provided that you have initialized application delegate itself.)
4. Now, you can use the value of application delegate that you have been set from view 2.

Comment: Apple recommends not using global variables, such as App Delegate, between VCs.

Comment: You can have substitute of global variable is to create a class using the Singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
NSString *string = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath] textLabel] text];
```

from view 2 and pass the string to view 1

Comment: How can I pass the string from view 2 to view 1, cause I'm not pushing from 2 to 1.  I'm popping from view 2 to view 1.